# How to perform XRANGE on Redis streams using spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, redis, stream

I am using below code to perform XRANGE operation on Redis Stream however it does not give any output even if the range have values in it. Is the approach in the below code correct or there needs to be a different way. I am using Spring Boot 2.2.4

```
String from = start + "-0";
String to = end + "-0";
Range<String> range = Range.closed(from, to);
        List<MapRecord<String, Object, Object>> mapRecords = template.opsForStream().range("SAMPLE.STREAM", range);
        Iterator<MapRecord<String, Object, Object>> iterator = mapRecords.iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            MapRecord<String, Object, Object> current = iterator.next();
            log.info("Record Id: {}, Stream: {}, Value: {}", current.getId(), current.getStream(), current.getValue());
        }
```

Comment: Please share logs of the error you are getting.

Comment: There is nothing printed in the errors either